# How to configure access to one container service from another container in CircleCI config

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, circleci

My `CircleCI` config file looks like below:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build_test:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.7.3
      - image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_DATABASE: test
          MYSQL_USER: test
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
```

Now I need to make my primary container (python) access the `mysql` service hosted by the mysql container. How do I configure that?

In docker-compose files, I can do this via `links`. How do I do that in `CircleCI` config?

I understand that one option is to put these in `docker-compose` and invoke `docker-compose up` from inside the CircleCI config. However, I am looking for a more elegant solution rather than depending on `docker-compose`.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "access". If you just want to connect to the MySQL database, then the networking address is just `localhost` - CircleCI use some networking trickery to attach the remote server to the localhost of the build container. By default this uses MySQL's default port, but I think you can change that, either by setting a specific `environment` value, or by using a custom command to start the MySQL server.

Comment: However if you want to set up a volume on that remote container, or `docker copy` into it, etc, then you cannot do that. The remote containers are quite isolated, presumably for security reasons.